# Template function with chrono::duration parameter and returning result of chrono::duration::count

Tags: c++, timer, c++-chrono, function-template

I'm trying to write a function that allows the user to specify a `chrono::duration` like `chrono::seconds` and return the result of `chrono::duration::count`.

I'm able to do this using the following template function:

```
template<typename D, typename Rep>
Rep getTimeSinceStart(){
    return chrono::duration_cast<D>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    };
```

To call this function, I must specify the type for `Rep`.  For example, assuming I have an object called `timer`, if `Rep` is a `long long`:

```
long long sinceStart = timer.getTimeSinceStart<chrono::seconds, long long>();
```

However, is there a way to just specify the `chrono::duration`?

I was thinking something like:

```
template<typename D>
D.rep getTimeSinceStart(){
    return chrono::duration_cast<D>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
};
```

This way I could just call:

```
long long sinceStart = timer.getTimeSinceStart<chrono::seconds>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

template<typename D>
typename D::rep getTimeSinceStart(){
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<D>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    long long sinceStart = getTimeSinceStart<std::chrono::seconds>();
    std::cout << "since start: " << sinceStart << std::endl;

}
```

in the above code, `start` is a global - you will want to make it a member of your class.

Comment: Awesome!  You can probably tell I'm relatively new to templates.  I did not know I needed to specify `typename` before `D::rep` on the return value.  If you have a reference where I can read more about this, I would appreciate the direction.

Comment: take a deep breath: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name